# How to set JS events at the right time

Tags: javascript, unobtrusive-javascript

In the rails.js that came with my rails (3.0.x, still with prototype), I see the following structure:

```
(function() {
// ...
document.on("click", ...
})();
```

What exactly is accomplished with the wrapping of the whole code in the anonymous function? Is this a valid way to delay the code until the dom has loaded or only the document object?

In my project, I currently have a lot of setup code inside a `Event.observe(document, 'dom:loaded', function() { ... }` block. I was wondering, if I should adopt the pattern above when I refactor my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have stumbled across the [module pattern](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/). It is useful because variables inside the immediately invoked function are local and don't pollute the global namespace.

```
(function(){
    var something = 17;
    //can use something inside here
}());

//but not here anymore
```

Not ethat there is no difference in timeing since the function is immediately invoked (in the final `()` bit)

Comment: I see, thank you. So I guess there is no problem with using the document object before dom:ready.

Comment: You can manipulate the document but you still have the same problems as before as far as ready-ness is concerned. You can only manipulate elements after they are created

Answer (score 1):

The self-invoking anonymous function will trigger what is inside immediately, which has nothing to do with delaying the code.

To make the code block inside be executed after the DOM is ready, you have to have DOMready listener. I guess the code you mentioned `Event.observe(document, 'dom:loaded', function() { ... }` is the one.

Comment: Another good practice is putting the code, which you want to run after the static HTML content, to the end of the body.